# Tree search (on data from a db) in php

Tags: php

i'm currently working on an application which require members to regiser under another member. a member can have a maximum of 5 members under him, bt each of those members can also have members under them. Pls how do i implement some sort of search to get all member under a specific member using php?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Why did you artificially limit the number of subordinate members?

Comment: i have basically asking this because i think there is no direct support for data structures in php & i' stuck. it's d application requirement that there cn be only 5 members directly under a single member

Comment: I don't know why this question was down-voted and closed. It was pretty easy to understand the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you try implementing the nested set model. It's bit complex to explain here but in a few lines of code but here are some links to get you started:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

http://threebit.net/tutorials/nestedset/tutorial1.html

Comment: thansk man 20 minutes I was looking for those links, that's exactly what I wanted to mention.

Comment: thanks man, the nested set model seem to be pretty cool idea